# Delete first occurrence of parentheses and their contents per line?

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

```
CustomerAccount, CustomerName(PayType), Address, (Amount)
```

I am trying to find a way to remove (PayType) from my example above using notedpad++.  Pay type is always the first set of parentheses but there are negative numbers also in parentheses in some lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^(]+\K\([^)]+\)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
  [^(]+     : 1 or more character that is not an open parenthesis
  \K        : forget all we have seen until this position
  \(        : an open parenthesis
  [^)]+     : 1 or more character that is not a close parenthesis
  \)        : a close parenthesis
```

**Result for given example:**

```
CustomerAccount, CustomerName, Address, (Amount)
```

Comment: @DarrenMcGettigan: You're welcome, glad it helps.